# WordPress REST API Global Search (API V2)

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I am looking for a way to run a global search query across all or multiple post types using WP REST API.

I am able to search posts using:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=test
```

In turn I am able to search pages using:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?search=test
```

How do I search across both posts and pages? I was able to do this in WP REST API V1 by specifying multiple `type[]` variables in the query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might be a bit late but there is an endpoint for that in the v2-api: `/wp-json/wp/v2/search`.

You can search for any specific `post_type` by supplying it via `subtype` or leave it to the default (`any`) to search in all post_types.

Edit: Of course you can also specifiy multiple with an array as you did before.

Comment: Can you give an example of this?

Comment: @JohnDee `/wp-json/wp/v2/search/?subtype=page&subtype=post` Arrays in query strings are done by redefining the key.  Cleaner `/wp-json/wp/v2/search/?subtype[]=page&subtype[]=post` (brackets to show it's an array. This needs to be added to work in forms). Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/. `subtype` can be any post type (try sending an invalid one for more info)

Comment: How do we include a search term with this?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar See the documentation I posted (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/#arguments), add a `search` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some examples using the REST API search endpoint for searching all content or specific content type(s).

**Search For a Term in All Site Content**

`/wp-json/wp/v2/search/?search=searchterm`

**Search For a Term and Limit Results to a Custom Post Type**

`/wp-json/wp/v2/search/?subtype=book&search=searchterm`

**Search For a Term and Limit Results to multiple Custom Post Types**

`/wp-json/wp/v2/search/?subtype[]=book&subtype[]=movie&search=searchterm`

[REST API Search Result Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/)